# Rspec does not show the random seed value. How can I see the seed value after rspec runs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, random-seed

I had an unusual failed example in rspec that I suspect is a flaky test. I scrolled back up to find the random seed rspec used, but it was not displayed as it usually is.

Can I discover the seed after the fact some other way?

Why is it no longer being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

When the order of the tests is set with `--order defined` , it does not display the seed because there simply is no seed to display. In this case, you can simply run the suite again with `--order defined` and should get identical test results.

In my case, I have that argument set in an alias, which obscured what was going on:

```
alias rsp='RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec --order defined --format d'
```

BTW, the seed *is* still displayed when you specify the seed with `--seed 123` :

```
Randomized with seed 123
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd **strongly** advise against using that alias. I wouldn't advise using `--order defined` in general, but if you must, it should absolutely be part of the application-specific rspec configuration.

Comment: Excellent advice, Tom. That alias is for a particular purpose. My regular rspec calls and all our CI integrations use random ordering.